# Add props to component of wrapped route in react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have routes that share the same behauvior, layout, etc. I'd like to pass props from layout to those components (Dashboard and Login) inside Route

My routes.js file is the following one

```
//imports omited    
export default (
    <AppLayout>
        <Route component={Dashboard} path="/" key="/" />
        <Route component={Login} path="/login" key="/login" />
    </AppLayout>
);
```

The render method of AppLayout.js has this code

```
const childrenWithExtraProp = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                component: React.cloneElement(child.props.component, {
                    functions: {
                        updateMenuTitle: this.updateTitle //function
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

This code results on numerous errors:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
    in Route
    in AppHeader
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by App)
    in App


Check the render method of `Route`.
    in Route
    in AppHeader
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by App)
    in App


Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

    Check the render method of `Route`.
        at invariant (invariant.js?7313:42)
        at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js?cada:5753)
        at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js?cada:7531)
        at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js?cada:7635)
        at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js?cada:7756)
        at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js?cada:7747)
        at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:7881)
        at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:7850)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:8225)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:10224)
```

At the last project I've worked we where using Routes inside Route, but at React-Router v4 this is not allowed.

Edit: before was something like this:

```
//Array of routes declared before
export default (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={General}>
            <IndexRoute component={Index} />
            {routes}
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from `component={Dashboard}` or `component={Login}`. Check what those two classes are. You may be exporting them incorrectly

Comment: @AndyRay before I had 

```const childrenWithExtraProp = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
   return React.cloneElement(child, {
    updateMenuTitle: this.updateTitle
   });
  });```

React App was working but I couldn't access to this.props.updateMenuTitle function from Dashboard component. If I'm not wrong, this means that my components work perfectly. I've tryied to remove this children mapping and everything works. The thing is that I'd like to pass props to components of Route and I don't know how.

Comment: Oh I see, you're cloning the route in AppLayout

Comment: @AndyRay is it forbidden (cloning a route)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the issue:

```
component: React.cloneElement(child.props.component, {
```

`child.props.component`  isn't a rendered component (like `<Dashbard />`), it's a *component class* (like `Dashboard`). [`cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) expects a rendered component. And you can't explicitly pass props extra into a *component class*.

There are a few ways you can achieve what you're doing. Cloning a Route feels "tricky" to me.

## Option 1: Higher order component with `updateTitle` logic

I would personally try making a **higher order component** (a function that takes a component class and returns a component class) that adds this prop, and exporting your Dashboard/Login components wrapped in it. Slightly more verbose but not as tricky:

HOC file:

```
const WithExtraProp = (ContentComponent) => {
    return WithPropWrapper extends Component {

        updateMenuTitle() {...}

        render() {
            // Add extra props here
            return <ContentComponent {...this.props} functions={{ updateMenuTitle: this.updateMenuTitle }}/>
        }

    }
}
export default WithExtraProp;
```

And in Dashboard

```
class Dashboard extends Component {...}
export default WithExtraProp(Dashboard);
```

With this method, you could also do (although I like it less)

```
<AppLayout>
    <Route component={WithExtraProp(Dashboard)} path="/" key="/" />
    <Route component={WithExtraProp(Login)} path="/login" key="/login" />
</AppLayout>
```

## Option 2: Use `<Route render={} />` instead of `component={}` to add props

**If you want to keep your current setup, where you implicitly/"magically" add props**, I don't see a way to do it without using the Route's `render` prop instead of `component`. This way you can render the component and pass in props normally.

You can keep this the same:

```
<Route component={Dashboard} path="/" key="/" />
```

And something like this:

```
const childrenWithExtraProp = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    // Clone the <Route />, remove the `component` prop, add `render` prop
    return React.cloneElement(child, {

        // Remove the `component` prop from the Route, since you can't use
        // `component` and `render` on a Route together. This way component
        // just becomes an API for this withExtraPropClass to use to find
        // the right component
        component: null,

        render = () => {
            const ChildComponent = child.props.component;
            const functions = {
                updateMenuTitle: this.updateTitle //function
            };
            return <ChildComponent functions={functions} />;
        }
        })
    });
});
```

## Option 3: Make `AppLayout` a higher order component

This is the same as option 1, where in the end you do this:

```
//imports omited
export default (
    <Route component={Dashboard} path="/" key="/" />
    <Route component={Login} path="/login" key="/login" />
);
```

And `AppLayout` is a higher order component that adds the prop.

```
const AppLayout = (ContentComponent) => {
    return WithPropWrapper extends Component {

        updateMenuTitle() {...}

        render() {
            // Add extra props here
            return (
                <MyLayoutStuff>
                    <ContentComponent {...this.props} functions={{ updateMenuTitle: this.updateMenuTitle }}/>
                </MyLayoutStuff>
            );
        }

    }
}
export default AppLayout;
```

and export your components wrapped in the layout:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {...}
export default AppLayout(Dashboard);
```

## Other thoughts

I personally have been using something closest to #3. Specifically, I have a file like `dashboard/Dashboard.js`, and in that same folder, `dashboard/index.js`, which exports Dashboard wrapped in a layout. You can see an example of that pattern at [this React boilerplate Github folder](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/tree/master/src/routes/home).

There are other options too. You could make an `<AppRoutes children=[{component: Dashboard, path="/"}, {...}] />` component that doesn't have to deal with cloning. If you need to do things with children on top of just `<render>`ing them, I generally prefer passing them in as an array instead of child components and mapping over them.

Comment: With the approach I've tryied, state of Dashboard contained "title"; one and unique.

With your approach the title is not maintained when browsing to other views (routes). Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think I understand your setup enough to answer your question. With both of the approaches I listed, `Dashboard` will have access to `this.props.updateTitle` and can do whatever it wants with it. It does require moving that method from AppALayout to the HOC, which might not be what you want?

Comment: But If I'd like to know the previous title from another component (like Login), I couldn't because the state can't be accessed. It is not shared with that HOC that you suggested.

Imagine that in a near future, I add the user information on AppLayout component. This user information could be accessed from any component and it would be always updated and from one unique source of truth (like Redux). Your "withExtraProps" component won't be updated. (If I'm not wrong)

Comment: You would have to move that logic out of AppLayout into the HOC, yes. I also edited my answer to include a way to do it with your current setup.